# Which linq query more productive

Tags: linq

Which linq query more productive

```
values.SelectMany(val => val.childs).Where(predicate)
```

or

```
values.SelectMany(val => val.childs.Where(predicate))
```

where val.childs is array Child[]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neither one should be significantly faster for most uses.